# How do I get the generated HTML ID of a form element?

Tags: forms

I have fields called

- 'title'
- 'field_article_summary'

The HTML IDs of the form elements are

- edit-title
- edit-field-article-summary-und-0

Is there a way to programmatically get these HTML IDs? (without writing the code myself to do it - Drupal must have something that is creating them)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There may be a Drupal method to accomplish what you need w/o explicitly needing the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is two years late but for anyone looking back at this, a way to get the element IDs is to use Drupal Form API's `#after_build` attribute to add a callback once the form has rendered.

```
$form['#after_build'] = array('mymodule_afterbuild'); // The callback can be called anything.
```

Then your function would look something like:

```
function mymodule_afterbuild(&$form, $form_state) {
  // Get the element ID.
  $id = $form['title']['#id'];
  // Then do something, such as passing it into Drupal settings to access with Javascript.
  drupal_add_js(array('mymodule_js_settings' => array('title_id' => $id)), 'setting');
  return $form;
}
```

Edit to say that the `#after_build` attribute can be used on individual elements in a form like so:

```
$form['title']['#after_build'] = array('mymodule_afterbuild');
```

This actually makes it easier to get the IDs, especially if you're using fieldsets, field collections or other complex field data structures.

Comment: This is one clever method to do this, though you could use `#attached` to add the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal uses the following two functions to prepare HTML classes and IDs:

- [`drupal_html_class()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_html_class/7), for generating a valid class name for an element
- [`drupal_html_id()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_html_id/7), for generating a valid ID for an element. This method also guarantees that the returned ID is unique.

Comment: drupal_html_id takes an id as an argument. I don't see how that helps me get the id from the drupal form element.

Comment: Drupal runs all elements through `drupal_html_id()` to get their ID...it's a one-way function though as there's an internal counter used to differentiate between duplicates. If you want the ID that has already been generated for a specific form element you'll need to check the element with something similar to this: `$id = $form['element']['#attributes']['id'];`.

Comment: thanks for your help. When I use $form['element']['#attributes']['id'] (or $form['element']['id'] or any variation) it is not set - so hence I need to get it programmatically. I have had a look at the source code for forms, and unfortunately it does not look to me like there is a single piece of code that does this, hence they may not be a 'good' way.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that's going to be quite tricky I think :/

Comment: I think I can work around it by manually setting the IDs. Is that bad? Is there a good reason not to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'bad', passing form elements through `drupal_html_id()` is mainly done to ensure a unique ID...if you can guarantee a unique id for certain elements yourself then it's absolutely fine to do it manually